# Can a spayed cat have kittens?

Tags: cats

I took in a cat from a cold cold snowy night; I have never owned a cat, only dogs, but I couldn't let this young cat stay out there. She is now my cat. She's female (which I did not know at the time), and had five kittens (three male, two female). The males went to new homes, and the females stayed with me.

I had all three spayed together; I dropped them all off, and picked them up next day, in their carriers. The spay was through a grant, so I expect they were around other cats. Now, one of them seems like she is pregnant; she's gained weight quickly, like pregnancy; her nipples are huge, and she seems uncomfortable and not herself. The other two have none of these symptoms.

Is it possible that, if she had "contact" with a male cat, then was spayed within 20 hours, she could be pregnant? Logically, I think not, but this is my first time as a cat owner. Common sense and life tells me no, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If she seems uncomfortable you should go and see the vet.

Comment: I have heard of a case where a supposedly spayed bitch became pregnant, in that case she came from a rescue centre and it sounded like someone had been mistaken (or lying?) about the spay.

Answer (score 8):

No, a cat that was spayed had an ovariectomy or ovariohysterectomy (removal of ovaries and uterus), so it would be impossible to have a pregnancy. Even if something was not done quite right (e.g. ovarian tissue left behind), while the cat might be able to go into heat she could not become pregnant.

It is common for cats to gain weight after being spayed, so this might be all you are seeing.

Very rarely we may see a [false pregnancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudopregnancy) after a spay, where there is visible mammary enlargement, but this will usually go away within a few weeks and is not a true pregnancy.

If you think there may be a medical problem then definitely please contact your vet.